# cpu shielding and disabling kernel interrupts

Tags: c, linux

Under Linux, what (if any) is the downside to disabling all interrupts on a particular CPU core, or even all cores on a single chip in a system containing multiple chips?  When writing a C program that has extreme sensitivity to latency, my natural urge is to isolate the thread on its own core and move all other tasks to separate cores, and I'm wondering what the tradeoffs are.

Comment: I suppose in your program you don't expect any input from periferies or having an exception thrown right?

Comment: Probably the answers are not valid in view of systemd, could a knowledgable person correct this, or add a note?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mainline Linux kernel is not designed to have all IRQs disabled on a CPU for an extended period. There are a number of internal kernel functions which require such IRQs - RCU being one of them. An RCU stall can and will bring down the rest of the system, and avoiding such a stall may (depending on the RCU implementation in use) involve IPIs (inter-processor interrupts) broadcasted to all CPUs.

That said, there are experimental patches to properly implement such CPU isolation; eg: http://lwn.net/Articles/268711/ - these go through all the internal gyrations needed to take a CPU offline (from the perspective of the rest of the kernel) before disabling interrupt routing. This is a fairly old patch series, though; you may want to contact the developer of the patch series to see if they have a newer version somewhere, or adapt those patches to the current version of the kernel. The PREEMPT_RT people are supposedly looking into implementing it as well - check out their wiki at https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page (it's not implemented yet, though). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

A couple things to consider:

1. Any IRQs will have one less processor to run on, which means you are more likely to have interrupts waiting. Obviously this becomes less of a problem as the number of processors grows.
2. Without interrupts, it will be much more difficult to force the process to give up execution. If it decides to enter an infinite loop, you can't interrupt the processor to stop it.

If you have complete trust that the process will give up control in a reasonable time and aren't worried about interrupt queueing, then it could be beneficial to disable interrupts.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the possibility of the process getting control of the processor and not relinquishing it due to a bug, many thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: If that's really true, what happens when the active thread tries to access an invalid address and gets a page fault? How could it not stop?

Comment: @Syncopated There is no way to ensure that will happen. What if it runs `while(1) {}`. That can be encoded as a single instruction and makes no data accesses, so it wouldn't cause a page fault once it starts.

Comment: I see, and the OS can't change the page table from under the process to force a page fault until it relinquishes control.